# Is there a way to import GTK bookmarks into Dolphin?

Tags: kde, gtk, dolphin

Is there a way to import GTK bookmarks (`.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`) into Dolphin (stored at `~/.local/share/user-places.xbel`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some one [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/57qic1/i_would_love_to_see_kde_and_gnome_using_the_same/d8u6zms/) created a solution:

```
for i in $(cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks); do
        printf '<bookmark href="%s"> <title>%s</title> </bookmark>' "$i" $(basename $(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/file\:\/\///g')) >> ~/.local/share/user-places.xbel

done
```

Run this in the terminal of your choice. (Then you'll have to edit the `xbel` file and make sure every bookmark tag is before `</xbel>` and remove incorrect nodes, since the script will create additional empty bookmarks if a bookmark had a custom name.)